# How to show an Error on the same page if user passes in existent ID

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and trying to learn CRUD by making a Blog application. When a user clicks on a specific post, a separate page gets opened with URL 127.0.0.1/posts/{id}

What I was wondering was, a viewer can easily try to write an ID of his own from the URL say 12 or 13 and laravel is showing an error when this happens. The error reads as

```
Trying to get property 'title' of non-object (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\lblog\resources\views\posts\post.blade.php)
```

Is there a way I can show something like "This post doesnt exsist" or something like that on the same page say *127.0.0.1/post/111*

If you want the code, it is attached below

**POST.BLADE.PHP**

```
@section('content')
    <div class="container" style="padding: 50px;">
        <h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
        <small>Created at: {{$post->created_at}}</small>
        <p>{{$post->body}}</p>
        <a href="/posts/update/{{$post->id}}" class="btn btn-success">Update this post</a>
        <a href="/posts/delete/{{$post->id}}" class="btn btn-danger">Delete this post</a>
        <a href="/posts" class="btn btn-primary">View all</a>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**POSTCONTROLLER.PHP**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('posts.post')->with('post', $post);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel has another method called [findOrFail()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    return view('posts.post')->with('post', $post);
}
```

If you use that, it will also display a nice `404` page when that blog post does not exist.

Edit: If you want to show it on the same page, you could probably do something like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id); // post will be null

    return view('posts.post')->with('post', $post);
}
```

In your blade file, you will do a check:

```
@if(! $post)
    <p>This post does not exist</p>
@else
    // display post here
@endif
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider upvoting/accepting the answer if it helped you :)